# How to design an api to be called by different applications

Tags: api, design-patterns

Application A has an api **setAge(String staffName)**. Application B and C both call this api.
If a staff Jack has different names in A, B, C: JackA, JackB, JackC, so how to design application A to map JackB=>JackA and JackC=>JackA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to model identity in some way. If your business objects (e.g. staff members) are persisted in a relational db you can use the table's primary key, but this is a rather bad practice, as technical keys should not be relied upon on the application level. Instead use a unique business-id for your entities. That can be a String or a UUID for example. When accessing the entities in your API, clients have to pass that business-id as a parameter.

If you are in an OO language like Java, you might have to consider implementing object equality through equals and hashCode contracts (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)).